# How can we run C++ Unit Test in Github Workflow?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, github, github-actions

I am using Microsoft Unit Testing Framework. I have successfully created and used the tests to check the program. I want to create an assignment for students where the same test cases can run as a workflow so that the assignments can be checked on every push on Github repository. How to configure the workflow so that the workflow use the test file in the folder to run the tests?

Comment: You need to configure a Github Action for it that will compile the code on every pull request and run the tests on it.

Comment: Yes I know. I am having trouble in configuring the workflow.How to configure the Actions so that the workflow use the test file to run tests?

Comment: Are you using CMake?

Comment: No, I'm using [Microsoft Unit Testing Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/getting-started-with-unit-testing?view=vs-2019)

Comment: The basic step involves something like [this](https://github.com/Waqar144/simplecrypto-cxx/blob/master/.github/workflows/ccpp.yml) but that is setup for CMake. You basically need to compile the code and run the executable. That's all. If you have a repository setup, I can take a look and attempt to make it work.

Comment: It will not work "as is", you will need to make quite a lot of modifications. If you are using `.sln` project, you will need the `MS-Build` action.

Comment: Okay. And yes it is .sln based project